# Knockout 3.2 components with named templates?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I'm trying to use the new components system in knockout 3.2.0.

There isn't much documentation at the moment, but this does work.

```
ko.components.register('price-input', {
  template: '<span>price-input</span>'
})
```

However the `template` binding allows you to specify a template name that already exists in the DOM, such as:

```
<script type="text/html" id="price_input">
  <span>price-input</span>
</script>
```

Then you could do this:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'price_input'}"></div>
```

So I tried this:

```
ko.components.register('price-input', {
  template: {name: 'price_input'}
})
```

but it doesnt work. Is there a way to use named templates with the new components, or must they be inline or loaded with AMD.

Thanks

Edit: After RP Niemeyer's answer, for clarification here is the template I tried his answer with:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ifx_price_input">
  <h4>PRICE INPUT <span data-bind="text: value"></span></h4>
</script>
```

Here is the component code:

```
ko.components.register('price-input', {
  template: {element: 'ifx_price_input'}
})
```

It does load the template, but treats it as an escaped string.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In v3.2.0 beta, this case wasn't handled well, hence the hackery needed by **InternalFX**.

**This will be fixed in v3.2.0 final.** It will work as you expect - simply reference a `script`, `template`, or `textarea` element, and its logical contents will be intepreted as template nodes.

In case you're interested, the commit that fixes and tests this is here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1454

Answer (score 8):

You can pass an `element` property that is either an element itself or a string that is the `id` of the element like:

```
template: { element: 'myTmpl' }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. This gets closer...But please see edits.

Comment: ooh, that actually looks like a bug.

Comment: I don't feel that we are handling this correctly. Discussing it in this thread: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1418 . I think we should fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this with some hackery...I hope this gets answered better by the knockout devs.

This works. Basically I just load the template text manually and pass it to the `register` function. So it works as if it was inline.

```
ko.components.register('price-input', {
  template: $('#ifx_price_input').html()
})
```